# Replacing keys in a dictionary with names found in a list of dictionaries PYTHON-FLASK

Tags: python, mysql, templates, flask, jinja2

I need to take this dictionary {'1': 9, '2': 5} (or one like it), and replace all the keys with their respective names from a database.

I was able to get the appropriate names from the database and put them in a list as dictionary entries. But now I'm in a bit of a pickle - the first dictionary needs to get their keys replaced with the keys in the names list I created from the database (which keeps giving me errors). The only other solution that I can personally think of is to find a way to get the database names and put them directly into the dictionary as opposed to a blank list, but I can't figure out how to do that using loops.

```
empty_list = [] **# stores it as [{"name": name1}, {"name":, name2},...]**
    for x in range(0, len(dict_key_array)):
        data = {
            "itm_num": dict_key_array[x]
        }
        mysql = connectToMySQL("app_database")
        query = "SELECT name, price FROM items WHERE items.id = %(itm_num)s;"
        pre_empty_list = mysql.query_db(query, data)
        empty_list.append(pre_empty_list)
```

---

I've tried this so far in order to get the names to take their respective places in the original dictionary:

```
for k in order_data.keys(): **# go through each key of dictionary**
        for x in range(0, len(order_data)): **# create a counter(? I think this would lead to duplicates, but I don't know how to avoid this)**
            neym = empty_list[x]['name'] **# template debugger says: "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"**
            order_data[neym] = order_data[k]
            del order_data[k]
```

I need to get the original dictionary of {'1': 9, '2': 5} (or one like it since this is based on an orders page and different orders will have different keys and values) to show up like {'pasta': 9, 'soda': 5} where 'pasta' and 'soda' are the names found in the database.

Comment: instead of `for x in range(0, len(order_data))` you could use `for item in order_data:`

Comment: Wouldn't that just give me each item in the dictionary as opposed to forming a counter for me?

Comment: yes, it gives each element in dict, but you use `x` also to get each element in dict - `dict_key_array[x]` - and you don't use `x` to count or anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it:

```
empty_list = []
    for x in range(0, len(dict_key_array), 2):
        data6 = {
            "itm_num": int(dict_key_array[x])
        }
        mysql = connectToMySQL("app_database")
        query = "SELECT name, price FROM items WHERE items.id = %(itm_num)s;"
        pre_empty_list = mysql.query_db(query, data)
        empty_list.append(pre_empty_list[0]['name'])



new_dict = {}
counter = 0
while counter < len(dict_val_array):
for name in empty_list:
            new_dict[name] = dict_val_array[counter]
            counter+=1

    session['new_dict'] = new_dict
```

Comments: I already had the dictionary of order items along with their quantities. I looped through that and put all the keys into a list, and put all the values into another list (dict_key_array and dict_val_array). What really changed this time around, however, was that instead of saving all my query results as a list, I specified which parts of my query results should be saved in the list, which is why I have above pre_empty_list[0]['name'], that would put the name alone in the list, and after this I used a while loop as a counter so that I enter each name in the list as a key and assign it the value found int he values list (dict_val_array).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if all is correct but it could be

```
# --- get names ---

mysql = connectToMySQL("app_database")
query = "SELECT name, price FROM items WHERE items.id = %(itm_num)s;"

empty_list = [] # **stores it as [{"name": name1}, {"name":, name2},...]**

for item in dict_key_array:
    result = mysql.query_db(query, {"itm_num": item})
    empty_list.append(result)

# --- convert keys in order ---    

order_data = {'1': 9, '2': 5} 

for key in order_data:
    index = int(key)-1 # convert str to int # key has value 1,2,3,... but list use 0,1,2,...
    name = empty_list[index]['name']
    order_data[name] = order_data.pop(key)
    #del order_data[key] # .pop() will remove it
```

But probably you should keep `name` with `itm_num` as dict `{itm_num1: {'name": name1}, itm_num2: {"name": name2} }` or even `{itm_num1: name1, itm_num2: name2}`

```
# --- get names ---

mysql = connectToMySQL("app_database")
query = "SELECT name, price FROM items WHERE items.id = %(itm_num)s;"

empty_dict = dict() # **stores it as {itm_num1: {'name": name1}, itm_num2: {"name": name2} }**

for item_num in dict_key_array:
    empty_dict[item_num] = mysql.query_db(query, {"itm_num": item_num})

# --- convert keys in order ---    

order_data = {'1': 9, '2': 5} 

for key in order_data:
    name = empty_dict[key]['name']
    order_data[name] = order_data.pop(key)
    #del order_data[key] # .pop() will remove it
```

Maybe you could even get it in one query `"SELECT id, name, price FROM items"`

```
result = mysql.query_db("SELECT id, name, price FROM items")
for row in result:
    empty_dict[row['id']] = row
```

but it will get all rows for database. But you can get it from database once and use `empty_dict` all the time with different orders.

Comment: I saw your answer just now, and I did not try it, but it looks like it should work as well. Thank you so much for your help. I came up with a solution that worked for me last night, and I posted it here as an Answer.